# My submenu not aligned with nav

Tags: html, css

```css
nav#primary_topmenu {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 5;

 width: 1300px;
 top:0%;
 text-align: center;
 
}

#topnav{

height: 85px;
background: rgba(29, 15, 6, 0.7);
width: 1300px;
}

#logotop img {
 
float:left;
margin-top: 5px;
}

nav#primary_topmenu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-indent: -9999px;
  color: #fff;

}

nav#primary_topmenu li {
 display:block;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding: 1em;
 
 font-weight: 900;
 font-family: 'Sorts Mill Goudy', "MS Mincho", serif;
 text-align: center;
 

 height: 3em;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 /*border: solid 1px #fff;*/
 }

nav#primary_topmenu ul {

 display: inline-block;
 height: 85px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background: rgba(29, 15, 6, 0.7);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#7E7E7E7E', EndColorStr='#7E7E7E7E');*/

}

nav#primary_topmenu li:hover {

 border-bottom: 4px solid #cd4650;
 
}

nav#primary_topmenu a:hover {
    color: #cd4650;
}

/*---- dropdown menu----*/

nav#primary_topmenu ul ul {
 display: none;
   position:fixed;
  top:88px;
  height:61px;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;

  }

nav#primary_topmenu ul ul li {
 float:none;
 display: block;
 height:20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-family: 'Sorts Mill Goudy', "MS Mincho", serif;
 border: 1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.1);
 box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background: rgba(29, 15, 6, 0.7);


}

nav#primary_topmenu ul li:hover > ul{ /*when hovering the parents please show the child*/
 display:block;
 padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav#primary_topmenu ul ul li a:hover {

 list-style-type: none;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="topnav">
<nav id="primary_topmenu">
      
       <ul>
                  <div id="logotop"><img src="images/coincopy.png">
            <li>
           
          <a class="introduction" href="#primary_topmenu li">Home</a>
           </li>
     <li>
      
         <a class="background" href="#background">Mission</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      
          <a class="ira" href="#ira">Fund <br>Placement</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      
          <a class="corporate" href="#corporate">Corporate <br>Finance</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      
          <a class="investment" href="#investment">Renewable <br> Energy</a>
     </li>
                    <li>
      
      <a class="consulting" href="#consulting">Team</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>
           </ul>
                    </li>

                     <li>
                    <a class="consulting" href="#consulting">Other <br>Services</a>

                     <ul>
                      
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>
            
           </ul>
                    </li>
                     <li>

                    <a class="consulting" href="#consulting">Licenses <br>& Compliance</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
      
      <a class="principal" href="#principal">Connections</a>
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
</div>
```

I try to align my submenu so that it is align exactly under the parents. Whenever I hover with the mouse to for example "Team" the submenu appear, but not align exactly where Team menu start.

I think it is because I have padding: 1em; at the `nav#primary_topmenu li.`
But then I have tried to add margin-left:-15px on `nav#primary_topmenu ul ul` in css, but it did not move.

How do I solve this? I tried to put padding: 0 and Margin:0 at the submenu li, but does not help...Please help me.

Comment: Please provide some codes. Preferably on [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) :)

Comment: please provide code here for us to look at; a JSFiddle is helpful but we definitely need the code in the question before we can help.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I have now added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this figured out ;).

The problem appears to be the "padding: 1em;" at the "nav#primary_topmenu li". As you expected. It moved the list by 1em to the right.

Your own solution didn't work because "nav#primary_topmenu ul li:hover > ul" resets the margins to 0 and overwrites your solution.

So the solution was simple. Add the "margin-left: -1em;" to "nav#primary_topmenu ul li:hover > ul" instead of "nav#primary_topmenu ul ul".

[This is the fiddle (fullscreen)](https://jsfiddle.net/dkh9p0mh/1/embedded/result/)

[This is the fiddle with code](https://jsfiddle.net/dkh9p0mh/1/)

PS: I also did a little fix to the moving navigation (last line of the css)

**HTML**

```
                <ul>
                     <div id="logotop"><img src="images/coincopy.png">
                     <li>

                      <a class="introduction" href="#primary_topmenu li">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                     <a class="background" href="#background">Mission</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                      <a class="ira" href="#ira">Fund <br>Placement</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                      <a class="corporate" href="#corporate">Corporate <br>Finance</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                      <a class="investment" href="#investment">Renewable <br> Energy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                        <a class="consulting" href="#consulting">Team</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                     <li>
                    <a class="consulting" href="#consulting">Other <br>Services</a>

                        <ul>

                            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu </a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                    <a class="consulting" href="#consulting">Licenses <br>& Compliance</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                        <a class="principal" href="#principal">Connections</a>
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
nav#primary_topmenu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 1300px;
    top:0%;
    text-align: center; 
}

#topnav{
height: 85px;
background: rgba(29, 15, 6, 0.7);
width: 1300px;
}

#logotop img {  
float:left;
margin-top: 5px;
}

nav#primary_topmenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: -9999px;
     color: #fff;
}

nav#primary_topmenu li {
    display:block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 1em;   
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Sorts Mill Goudy', "MS Mincho", serif;
    text-align: middle;
    height: 3em;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*border: solid 1px #fff;*/
    }

nav#primary_topmenu ul {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 85px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: rgba(29, 15, 6, 0.7);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#7E7E7E7E', EndColorStr='#7E7E7E7E');*/
}

nav#primary_topmenu li:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #cd4650;
}

nav#primary_topmenu a:hover {
    color: #cd4650;
}

/*---- dropdown menu----*/

nav#primary_topmenu ul ul {
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
    top:88px;
    height:61px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }

nav#primary_topmenu ul ul li {
    float:none;
    display: block;
    height:20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Sorts Mill Goudy', "MS Mincho", serif;
    border: 1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: rgba(29, 15, 6, 0.7);
}

nav#primary_topmenu ul li:hover > ul{ /*when hovering the parents please show the child*/
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: -1em; /*the dropdown displayed too much to the right because of the 1em padding in nav#primary_topmenu li. This moves the dropdown back by the same amount. */
}

nav#primary_topmenu ul ul li a:hover {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav#primary_topmenu ul li{
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent; /*prevents navigation from moving when applying the bottom border on hover*/    
}
```